# Sphero FrontLEDOutputCommand replacement

Tags: android, sphero-api

Wondering how you get the FrontLED to turn on to tell where the sphero is pointing.  When i tried to use FrontLEDOutputCommand.SendCommand(mRobot, 1.0f) eclipse tells me this command is depricated.  Would like to use this command.

Answer (score 2):

The structure that you are using here has in fact been deprecated for quite some time now. There is no real front LED, the LED is actually positioned on the back of the board. Additionally, with the release of the newer SDK, the syntax has changed a bit as well.

To write this line now (and not get deprecation notices with the new SDK) you do:

```
mRobot.setBackLEDBrightness(1.0f);
```